# How to find comination of values which comes out of binomial coefficient

Tags: probability

like power set of {abc} can be found out using 3 digits of binary,
like following.
    Subset
    000 { }
    001 {c}
    010 {b}
    011 {b,c}
    100 {a}
    101 {a,c}
    110 {a,b}
    111 {a,b,c}

in similar fashion i wanted to know the sets of C(n,r)=n!r!(n−r)!

yours sincerley

**"section B"**

i have revised and written it again.

what i could understand is,
like

"1" has too options,(exist or not exists and it will be less than "3")

"2" has four options, it can be less than "1" , greater than "1" and less than "3", greater than "3"  and exist or not exist.

"3" has too options,(exist or not exists and it will be greater than "1")

Q1) will it be 3*4*3=36

that is i can formualte it like,
i have three choices like (a,b,c),(b,a,c),(b,c,a)
and "all are optinal".

so, should I find the sets for each of them sepratlly, then decide which suite my case.

**"or there is any systematic way".**

Q2) other thing is , it is quite eazy to find them manually for small numbers, how can i find
it for big number , please solve one problem so that i can udersatand.

yours sincerley

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not clear (at least to me) what you are asking, or what the relation is between your question and your subset example.

Answer (score 1):

To list them you can use a recursive function.  There are $n \choose r$ total combinations. Of those, ${n-1 \choose r}=\frac {(n-1)!}{(n-r-1)!r!}=$ do not include the first element and ${n \choose r}-{n-1 \choose r}=\frac {(n)!}{(n-r)!r!}-\frac {(n-1)!}{(n-r-1)!r!}=\frac {(n-1)!}{(n-r-1)!r!}\cdot \frac r{n-r}={n-1 \choose r-1}$ do include the first element.  So start with the right number of elements of you list that include/exclude the first element, then do the $n-1$ case for each.

Comment: My procedure will provide the list of sets of a given size (which is what C(n,r) enumerates.)  In your case, if $n=3,r=2$ it would provide $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}$  I don't understand what you are asking about a and b.  Your list in the comment is the same one as in your question and includes all subsets of any size.  In that case you don't want combinations.

Comment: how can i find the sets from following situation. 
i have three numbers,{1 2 3} which will always be in this order {123},
i want to find out number of cases can be made, 
.
 but 2 can come at frist position that is before 1 or at second position or at 
third position that is after 3.
and all are optional


please tel me step wise using formulas to the set combination, so that i can understand, also,
 any link will be helpfull.
 yours sincerly

Comment: You have to carefully think through the cases.  It sounds like for this question you have all elements in the "set"  (sets usually do not depend on order), that $1$ has to come before $3$, but $2$ can go anywhere.  Once you choose where $2$ goes in the order (three choices), the order is fixed, so three.  Your writing of questions seems very disorganized.  I am guessing what your questions are-if you work on making them clear you may be able to understand what you are after and be able to solve them yourself.

Comment: i have added some thing in "section B" of my primary question, and tried to solve it, please check it.